# Can I use getInitialProps in _app.js and in pages?

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm working on my first serious NextJS app. I have it set up to pull in JSON data for the left nav, rather than hardcoding them in the app somewhere. This way I don't have to rebuild every time there's a minor change to the site's navigation.

Since the navigation needs to be available on every page, I added `getInitialProps` to the `_app.js` file, which grabs the left nav and passes it to the left nav component. But now as I'm moving on to build the homepage, I see that the `getInitialProps` there does not run. It seems that the `getInitialProps` in `_app.js` takes precendence.

Is there a way to have both? Or some other workaround that accomplishes the goal (or just a better way to do this in general)?

Note that I'm using `getInitialProps` for two reasons:

1. getStaticProps is out because I don't plan to build the entire site at build time
2. getServerSideProps is *usually* out because I don't like that it ends up doing two http requests: first a request goes to the `NextJS` server, then the server sends a request to my API (which happens to live on a different server). If I'm just getting basic stuff like the navigation, there's no need for `getServerSideProps` to run on the `NextJS` server, I'd rather skip the middle man

Here's some some simplified code:

*_app.js*:

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import axios from "axios";

import store from "../store";
import Header from "../components/Header";
import LeftNav from "../components/LeftNav";

function MyApp(props) {
    const { Component, pageProps } = props;

    return (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Header />
            <LeftNav leftnav={props.leftnav} />
            <Component { ...pageProps } />
        </Provider>
    )
}

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    let config = await import("../config/config");
    let response = await axios.get(`${config.default.apiEndpoint}&cAction=getLeftNav`);

    if (response) {
        return {
            leftnav: response.data.leftNav
        };
    } else {
        return {
            leftnav: null
        };
    }
};

export default MyApp;
```

*Home.js*:

```
import axios from "axios";

const Home = (props) => {
    console.log("Home props", props);
    return (
        <div>home</div>
    );
};

Home.getInitialProps = async(context) => {
    
    // this only runs if the getInitialProps in _app.js is removed :(

    let config = await import("../config/config");
    let response = await axios.get( `${config.default.apiEndpoint}&cAction=getHome` );
    if ( response ) {
        return {
            home: response.data.home
        };
    } else {
        return {
            home: null
        }
    }
};
export default Home;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to call `App.getInitialProps(context)` in your `_app` to call the current page's `getInitialProps`. You can then merge the page's props with the remaining props from `_app`.

```js
import App from 'next/app'

// Remaining code...

MyApp.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
    const pageProps = await App.getInitialProps(context); // Retrieves page's `getInitialProps`
    
    let config = await import("../config/config");
    let response = await axios.get(`${config.default.apiEndpoint}&cAction=getLeftNav`);

    return {
        ...pageProps,
        leftnav: response?.data?.leftNav ?? null
    };
};
```

From the [custom `_app`](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-app) documentation:

> When you add `getInitialProps` in your custom app, you must `import App from "next/app"`, call `App.getInitialProps(appContext)` inside
> `getInitialProps` and merge the returned object into the return value.